# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::when()

Tags: laravel-5

I'm getting the error of undefined `when()` method in laravel 5 when use **Database: Query Builder Conditional Statements**

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#conditional-statements

Call to undefined method `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::when()`

```
$job = $request->input('Job');
$EmpDetails = DB::table('EMPLOYEES')->when($job, function ($query) {
    return $query->where('Job', '=', $job);
})->get();
print_r($EmpDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$EmpDetails = DB::table('EMPLOYEES')->where('JOB',$job)->get();
```

I think this should work.

Edit: You might want to use advance where. In that case:

```
$EmpDetails = DB::table('EMPLOYEES')->where(function($query) use ($job)
        {
            $query->where('JOB',$job);
        })->get()
```

Comment: This is work fine but my requirement in not fulfil. please see https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#conditional-statements why we use when() function